# How can I show hints for droppeddown TComboBox items in Delphi 10.3.3?

Tags: delphi, hint, tcombobox

I have to show hints for the dropped down `TComboBox` items.

For this, I could use the `OnMouseMove` event to handle the hovering message. It takes the mouse X,Y client coordinates as parameters. If I could determine which is the first item to draw (dropdown list with a vertical scrollbar) then I could determine the item under the cursor using the `ItemHeight` value.

Is there any Win32 API call of message to get this value? The IDE does not support this information, or I couldn't find it.

Comment: Try using [`GetComboBoxInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo) to get the `HWND` of the ComboBox's drop-down list, then send the list a [`LB_ITEMFROMPOINT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/lb-itemfrompoint) message,

Comment: @RemyLebeau I got to the CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO message myself as well. Thx for the LB_ITEMFROMPOINT info. Unfortunatelly as I can see the OnMoseMove does not handle DropDownList mouse events. So I have to handle these messages in the overriden TMyForm.WndProc. But what kind of message should I catch for this? WM_MOUSEMOVE? But how can I know it is the DrapDownList event and not one triggered by the TForm itself?

Comment: For that, you would have to subclass the drop-down list to assign a separate WndProc directly to it via `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)` or `SetWindowSubclass()` (see [Subclassing controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview) and [How to Subclass a Combo Box](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclass-a-combo-box)). You can use the `TComboBox.OnDropDown` event to set the hook, and then use the `TComboBox.OnCloseUp` event to remove the hook.

Comment: It's not an answer, but for user experience, show a hint on item to select the correct value is not really clear. Why don't use value more understable for user ?

Comment: @Bosshoss It is needed for  OwnerDraw graphic combobox-es. It counl not be more understandable. I would like to use the hint to show the parameters needed to generate the graphic content.

Comment: @RemyLebeau
What is the Delphi signature of the `SubClassProc` in the example? `LRESULT CALLBACK SubClassProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)`

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper `function SubClassProc(hwnd: HWND; msg: UINT; wParam: WPARAM; lParam: LPARAM): LRESULT; stdcall;` but I suggest you use `SetWindowSubclass()` (new style) instead of `SetWindowLongPtr(GWLP_WNDPROC)` (old style)

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use an cxOwnerDrawXXXX style ComboBox and the OnDrawItem event which tells you when you are drawing a focused item. I used this method myself once to update a static hint in a text box that provides more information on the focused / hovered over item.

Example putting hint text in a StaticText control:

```
procedure TForm1.ComboBox1CloseUp(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StaticText1.Caption := '';
end;

procedure TForm1.ComboBox1DrawItem(Control: TWinControl; Index: Integer; Rect:
    TRect; State: TOwnerDrawState);
begin
  // Update a hint on a static control
  if  (odSelected in State) and (Control as TComboBox).DroppedDown  then
    StaticText1.Caption := 'Hint for value:' + (Control as TComboBox).Items[Index];

  // Draw list item
  with (Control as TComboBox).Canvas do
  begin
    FillRect(Rect);
    TextOut(Rect.Left, Rect.Top, (Control as TComboBox).Items[Index]);
  end;
end;
```

Could be adapted to activate/show/store a hint instead of updating a static control.

Comment: It just modify the hint on item draw event. It does not work when the list is dropped down and I just hoovering with the mouse.